# $wpdb Ajax not redirecting to main page

Tags: ajax, wpdb

I'm having difficulty with redirecting a page once a person submits data. I made a form, and when the user clicks 'Add student', the data would be encoded through json, stored in the database. The page would be would be redirected and refreshed by a custom jQuery class, which refers to a blank div with a class called "messageDiv" (first line of code dispayed below.

However, when a user submits data, they are taken a blank white page with the json string echoing a success or failure upon submission. I'm not sure why the page is not being redirected correctly, and why it takes the user to a blank json page.

How the success message is supposed to be displayed:

```
<div class="messageDiv"></div>
```

My ajax code:

```
jQuery(function() 
    {
        jQuery("#myForm").submit(function(event) 
        {
            event.preventDefault();
        
        // ajax function
        jQuery.ajax
            ({
                dataType: "json",
                type: "post",
                data: jQuery("#myForm").serialize(),
                url: "../admin-ajax.php",
                success:function(data) 
                {
                
                    jQuery(".messageDiv").html(data.message);
                    
                    if(data.status == 1)
                    {
                        jQuery("#myForm").trigger('reset');
                    }
                },

            });
        });
        
    });
```

The backend database query and connection:

```
if(isset($_POST['BtnSubmit']))
{
    global $wpdb;
    
    $data_array = array(
        'first_name' => $_POST['first_name'],
        'last_name' => $_POST['last_name']
        );
        
        $table_name = 'students';
        
        $rowResult = $wpdb->insert($table_name, $data_array, $format=NULL);
        
        
        if($rowResult == 1) 
        {        
            echo json_encode(array('message' => '<h1>Form added into the database<h1>', 'status' => 1));
        } else 
        {
            echo json_encode(array('message' => '<h1>Error Form submission<h1>', 'status' => 0));
        }
        
        die();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by redirect? I don't see any redirecting happening here?

Comment: When a user clicks the submit button, the page should refresh, meaning the page should be redirected back to itself, along with the upated data. I am newer to Ajax, and am unfamiliar with how to redirect pages without using the header() function

Comment: Well redirecting pages with JavaScript is not really related to WordPress, so this isn't really the place to ask. Have you searched for "refresh page JS" or anything like that? There's many examples available.

Comment: You can add `location.reload()` after form reset.